# I need one message to be displayed out of 10. but it displays all 10 at the same time

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a roblox game using lua. in it i want a player to stand on a block which will turn red and display a randomly chosen message from 10 messages. But all 10 messages are being displayed.

```
local block = script.Parent
local originalColor = block.BrickColor
local messages = {
    "Message 1",
    "Message 2",
    "Message 3",
    "Message 4",
    "Message 5",
    "Message 6",
    "Message 7",
    "Message 8",
    "Message 9",
    "Message 10"
}

local function onTouched(part)
    local humanoid = part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        block.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright red")
        local text = Instance.new("BillboardGui", block)
        text.Adornee = block
        text.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
        text.StudsOffset = Vector3.new(0, 2, 0)
        local label = Instance.new("TextLabel", text)
        label.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
        label.Text = messages[math.random(#messages)]
        label.TextSize = label.TextSize + 10
        label.TextColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
        label.BackgroundTransparency = 1
        wait(3)
        block.BrickColor = originalColor
        text:Destroy()`your text`
    end
end

block.Touched:Connect(onTouched)
```

Comment: Can you try putting `local text = Instance.new("BillboardGui", block)` and `local label = Instance.new("TextLabel", text)` out of `onTouched` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that as you walk over the part, the touched event can fire multiple times. To prevent this you can use something that is often called 'debounce' this prevents the event from being fired too often.

By checking if debounce is false, it prevents the event from being fired in quick succession.

```lua
local debounce = false

local function onTouched(part)
    local humanoid = part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if humanoid and not debounce then
        block.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright red")
        local text = Instance.new("BillboardGui", block)
        text.Adornee = block
        text.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
        text.StudsOffset = Vector3.new(0, 2, 0)
        local label = Instance.new("TextLabel", text)
        label.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
        label.Text = messages[math.random(#messages)]
        label.TextSize = label.TextSize + 10
        label.TextColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
        label.BackgroundTransparency = 1
        debounce = true
        wait(3)
        block.BrickColor = originalColor
        text:Destroy()
        
        debounce = false
    end
end
```